# Multiple SQL tables to inherit from one parent table in loop

Tags: sql, python-2.7, postgresql-9.6

Can someone try and point me in the right direction : I have many SQL tables of cities (`city_table`) in a state. All the tables are already built and populated. I want to write a script/query to have all the cities inherit from state table (`state_table`). I do have all the cities in a list which can be easily added to a Python script or SQL.

I know that I can use the SQL query `ALTER TABLE <child_table> INHERIT <parent_table>;` to have the child inherit from the parent, but this method only works one at a time and I want to do this for each city in any given state and do not want to perform this task manually.